# Simplifying probability

Tags: probability

Is it possible to simplify the follwoing expression?

\begin{align}
P(c_0=r_a|k=3)&P(c_1=r_a|k=3)+\\
P(c_0=r_b|k=3)&P(c_1=r_b|k=3)+\\
P(c_0=r_c|k=3)&P(c_1=r_c|k=3)
\end{align}

where:

\begin{align}
P(c_0=r_a)+P(c_0=r_b)+P(c_0=r_c)=1
\end{align}

and

\begin{align}
P(c_1=r_a)+P(c_1=r_b)+P(c_1=r_c)=1
\end{align}

There is not other $r$ value than $r_a$, $r_b$ and $r_c$
 available.

I played around and got $P(c_0=c_1|k=3)$, but I think that's wrong.

Maybe someone can help me?

Thank you

Comment: I am completely unsure which rule I have to use. I just played around and used "intuition" (i think intuition and probability theory is often a bad combination). Could you shortly explain which rules you used? Thank you:)

Comment: If $c_0$ and $c_1$ are conditionally independent of each other given $k=3$ and if your two "where" statements are also true given $k=3$, then your suggested simplification is correct, but otherwise there are counterexamples and there may be no simplification possible

Comment: I think the rules of probability you can use here are $P(A, B) = P(A \vert B)P(B) = P(B \vert A)P(A)$ and that $P(A) = \sum_{i} P(A, B_{i})$ that with the previous one is $P(A) = \sum_{i} P(A \vert B_{i})P(B_{i})$. So I would say the most you can do in your expression is left it as $P(c_0 = r_{a}, c_1 = r_{a}\vert k = 3) + P(c_0 = r_{b}, c_1 = r_{b}\vert k = 3) + P(c_0 = r_{c}, c_1 = r_{c}\vert k = 3)$